# Writing a simple matrix class in common lisp for practice

Tags: matrix, lisp, elisp, common-lisp

Common lisp newbie. Writing lisp code is quite different from writing c++/java, as I wrote them before.

I am trying to write a simple matrix class in common lisp for practice. Some codes like that:

```
(defun make-matrix (row col)
  (make-list row :initial-element (make-list col :initial-element nil)))

(defun init-matrix (matrix init-value)
  (labels ((set-element-value (lst)
                              (if (and lst
                                       (listp lst))
                                  (mapcar #'set-element-value lst)
                                (setf lst init-value))))
    (set-element-value matrix)))

(defun matrix+ (&rest matrices)
  (apply #'mapcar (lambda (&rest rows)
                    (apply #'mapcar #'+ rows)) matrices))
```

My question is can I write a matrix+ accepting different number of arguments without 'apply', or in a better way ? In a way that lisp should be?

And how about the matrix*, can somebody show me some awesome code accepting arbitrary number of arguments in matrix* ? Thanks.

Comment: @wvxvw I will take a look later.

Answer (score 5):

Common Lisp has n-dimensional arrays. I would use those for matrix operations.

See: `MAKE-ARRAY`, `AREF`, ...

Typically I would also then write a binary (taking two arguments) matrix operation. Use then `REDUCE` to operate over a list of matrices.

```
CL-USER > (make-array '(3 5) :initial-element 0)
#2A((0 0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0 0))
```

Above creates a 2-dimensional array of size 3x5 with 0 as initial content.

Comment: Maybe I should stop this simple practice and find something instead ... I will see the document for more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Matrix multiplication. I can't promise this is the best example possible, but it is really straight-forward. This is given you use arrays rather than lists. Also, of course, you can optimize for square matrices, or special cases, like identity matrices etc. But this is meant only to be simple, not efficient etc.

```
(defun matrix* (&rest matrices)
  (assert (cdr matrices) nil
          "You will achieve nothing by multiplying a single matrix.")
  (reduce
   #'(lambda (a b)
       (assert (= (array-dimension a 0) (array-dimension b 1)) nil
               "The number of rows in the first matrix should be the number ~
                of columns in the second matrix")
       (let ((result
              (make-array
               (list (array-dimension a 1) (array-dimension b 0))
               :initial-element 0)))
         (dotimes (i (array-dimension a 1) result)
           (dotimes (j (array-dimension b 0))
             (dotimes (k (array-dimension a 0))
               (incf (aref result i j) (* (aref a k i) (aref b j k))))))))
   matrices))

(format t "result: ~s~&" (matrix* #2A((1 2) (3 4)) #2A((5 6) (7 8))))
;; #2A((23 31) (34 46)) =
;; (1 * 5 + 3 * 6 = 23) (1 * 7 + 3 * 8 = 31)
;; (2 * 5 + 4 * 6 = 34) (2 * 7 + 4 * 8 = 46)
```